# How to fit a time-delay variable to data in R?

Tags: r, data-modeling, differential-equations, timedelay

I have two datasets that are known (or suspected) to be a similar shape, but with the second dataset delayed by time tau and scaled by a factor mu:

F(t)

C(t)=mu*F(t+tau)

I have data for both C(t) and F(t), and I have fit a differential equation model to F as well and generated numerical solutions in R. I also have an estimate for mu. What I need is a way to fit for parameter tau. I have been using nls.lm and optim for parameter fitting so far, but I do not know how to fit a time delay. If it helps, I have an equation for F'(t) in terms of F.

What is the best way to fit for tau using R? I would like a method where I could later simultaneously fit for mu as well, if possible.

Comment: Cross-correlation analysis?

Comment: Have you tried `optimize()`?

Comment: a [mcve] would help a lot with answers, if you can really make it minimal (i.e. a "toy" example)

Answer (score 0):

I've fitted ODE for Pharmacokinetics and drug dissolution analysis with lag-time parameter. This is an example of a Weibull profil used to fit cumulated percent of drug dissolved vs time:

```
weibull2<-function(x,lwo,lbeta,lgama,Tlag){
  # overrides convergence problems
  # parameter redefined to be positive 
  beta<-exp(lbeta)
  gama<-exp(lgama)
  wo<-exp(lwo) 

  # lag time: 
  n=length(x)
  tps<-x - Tlag
  # split time vector tps in positive and negative
  tps.posit<-tps[tps>0]
  tps.negat<-tps[tps<=0]
  # time vector repeating 0   
  tps<-c(rep(0,length(tps.negat)),tps.posit)
  v<-wo*(1-exp(-(tps/beta)^gama))
  v
}

# PK model example, using package nlmeODE
foWeibDerR<-function(x,wo,beta,gama,Tlag,alfa,ka,Fer,escala){
  tps<-x - Tlag
  tps.posit<-tps[tps>0]
  tps.negat<-tps[tps<=0]
  tps<-c(rep(0,length(tps.negat)),tps.posit)
  Idx<-c(rep(1,length(tps[tps<10])),rep(0,length(tps[tps>=10])))
  v<-alfa*ka*exp(-ka*x) + Idx*Fer*(1-alfa)*(wo/100)*gama*(tps^(gama-1))*exp(-(tps/(beta*escala))^gama)/((beta*escala)^gama)
  v
}
```

In my experience if else statments didn't work for me. I fitted weibull with nls and the ODE model by using optim() minimizing the sum of squared residuals as objetive function:

```
# SELECTED MODEL
pkWeibModMphFO<-function(t, y, k) {
  list(c(
    D.Test*foWeibDerT(t,coefMTV.FAST[1], coefMTV.FAST[2], coefMTV.FAST[3], exp(k[5]),
                     (alpha.test)/100, exp(k[1]), exp(k[4]), exp(k[7]))/exp(k[2]) - exp(k[3])*y[1],
    D.Ref*foWeibDerR(t,coefCon.FAST[1], coefCon.FAST[2], coefCon.FAST[3],exp(k[6]),
                     (alpha.con)/100, exp(k[1]), exp(k[4]), exp(k[7]))/exp(k[2]) - exp(k[3])*y[2]
  ))
}


# Objetive function to minimize (Least Square of Residuals)
errFnOLS.fast<-function(parToOptim) {
  yini<-c(y1=0, y2=0)
  sim<-ode(y=yini, func=pkWeibModMphFO, times=tiempos, parms=parToOptim)
  residA<-MTV.plasma.FAST[,2] - sim[indxA,2]
  residB<-con.plasma.FAST[,2] - sim[indxB,3]
  scr<-sum(c(residA,residB)^2)
  print(sqrt(scr))
}

# Ordinary Least Squares - OLS
salida.OLS.FO<-optim(parametros, fn=errFnOLS.fast, method="BFGS")
exp(salida.OLS.FO$par)
```

Comment: isn't this going to be hard to optimize because the shift is effectively an integer?

Comment: No, I've used increments of 0.25  fom 0 to 36 hours which worked for me `tiempos<-seq(0,36, 0.25) `